# Proplem with special characters

Tags: php, arrays, input, str-replace

everybody,
I have a problem with the special characters.
I would have to make many entries with an array and there are special characters like this " and ' with it.
If I put this in an input like this, it will be displayed.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="&quot;A&quot; Cell Incubator">
```

But if I use a "str_replace" to help, nothing is displayed.

```html
    <?php
 $suche  = array("&quot;");
 $ersetze = array('"');
 $text  = "&quot;A&quot; Cell Incubator";
 $texts  = "&quot;A&quot; Cell Incubator";
?>
<ul class="">
 <li><h1>Sonderzeichen "</h1>
  <ul class="">
   <li><?php echo str_replace($suche, $ersetze, $text); ?></br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo str_replace($suche, $ersetze, $text); ?>"></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to display the HTML code for special characters in the input.

Comment: Have you looked at `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use htmlentities:

```
<ul class="">
    <li><h1>Sonderzeichen "</h1>
        <ul class="">
            <li><?php echo str_replace($suche, $ersetze, $text); ?></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo htmlentities($text); ?>"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```